# Controller using Spark framework is nesting html in <pre>

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, rest, freemarker, java

I'm trying to use [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/) and [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) as the framework for a site I'm building. For now, I'm just going through the tutorial and trying to implement Bootstrap with it all as well. Everything is working in the sense that Spark is properly mapping my resource file to the proper endpoint. However, for some reason it seems to be nesting all of my html in a pre element so that all that displays on my endpoint is the raw html.

Here's what I have:

The controller:

```
import static spark.Spark.get;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import spark.ModelAndView;
import spark.template.freemarker.FreeMarkerEngine;

public class BulkUploadController extends BaseController {

    private static final String CONTROLLER_ROOT = "/bulk-upload";

    @Override
    public void registerEndpoints() {

        get(CONTROLLER_ROOT, 
                (request, response) -> {
                    Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
                    return new ModelAndView(attributes, "bulk-upload.ftl");
                }, new FreeMarkerEngine()); 
    }

}
```

The main method in ApiServer.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiServer apiServer = new ApiServer();
        apiServer.init();
    }

private void init() {       
        setupEndpoints();
    }

private void setupEndpoints() {
BulkUploadController bulkUploadController = new BulkUploadController();
bulkUploadController.registerEndpoints();
}
```

My view (bulk-upload.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Bulk Uploader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Bulk Uploader</h1>
            <p>Other stuff will go here</p>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

So all of that html is not being set as the rootof my endpoint, but rather being nested as I described above. Any ideas why this might me happening?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured it out. I'll post the answer here in case others are confused about the same thing.  To get this working, I needed to change the controller to add this:

```
response.type("text/html");
```

so:

```
get(CONTROLLER_ROOT, 
                (request, response) -> {
                    response.type("text/html");
                    Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
                    attributes.put("dvfcs", new Object());
                    return new ModelAndView(attributes, "bulk-upload.ftl");
                }, new FreeMarkerEngine());
```